# Is there a default limit on uploading images and documents for JSON REST API (.Net Core)?

Tags: json, rest

I am working on Rest JSON API for internal company social network. One of the methods should upload files and store it into a file server. 
The main use-case is a uploading files for employers posts. For example it can be some images and documents (.pdf, .doc, .xls). I don't know what limit to set on the maximum file size on the server's side. 
I think, that I can set a default limit of 50 mb megabytes per file. Is it a good practice? Is there any best practices for this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to limit file size especially if you have a lot of traffic, which should be the case for a social network.
As long as the company doesnt require large single files to be exchange it is usually safe to do so.

In case you need to be share big files, you can reserve an address and change the limit for this one, but restrict its access (Administration rights, ...).

It is also good pratice to filter the file extension to increase security since you specified images and documents.

I would recommend doing a test run with a few employees to tweak the limit to desire level.

In short, it is good practice but it'll depend on the company and program needs, also to the amount of storage available.